# Use structs with Golang syscall on Windows?

Tags: winapi, go

The [`EnumPrinters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 function takes and argument `_Out_ LPBYTE  pPrinterEnum`, a pointer to an allocated buffer. In C, it works like this:

```
DWORD cbNeeded, nPrinters;
EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 5, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded, &nPrinters);

BYTE *pPrnInfo = malloc(cbNeeded);
EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 5, pPrnInfo, cbNeeded, &cbNeeded, &nPrinters);

PRINTER_INFO_5 *pPrinterInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_5 *) pPrnInfo;
for (int i=0; i < nPrinters; i++) {
  printf("pPrinterName: %s\n", pPrinterInfo[i].pPrinterName);
}
```

How is the same accomplished in Go, using `syscall` instead of cgo? So far, this much compiles, but I don't know how to cast the resulting byte slice to an array of structs (without using cgo).

```
type PrinterInfo5 struct {
    pPrinterName             *uint16
    pPortName                *uint16
    attributes               uint32
    deviceNotSelectedTimeout uint32
    transmissionRetryTimeout uint32
}

...

dll := syscall.MustLoadDLL("winspool.drv")
f := dll.MustFindProc("EnumPrintersW")

var cbNeeded, nPrinters uint32
fmt.Println(cbNeeded, nPrinters)
f.Call(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, 0, 5, 0, 0, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&cbNeeded)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&nPrinters)))
fmt.Println(cbNeeded, nPrinters)

var pPrnInfo []byte = make([]byte, cbNeeded)
f.Call(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, 0, 5, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pPrnInfo)), uintptr(cbNeeded), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&cbNeeded)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&nPrinters)))
```

I have tried this, which prints one iteration successfully, then fails with `fatal error: heapBitsBulkBarrier: unaligned arguments`:

```
hdr := reflect.SliceHeader{
  Data: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pPrnInfo)),
  Len:  int(nPrinters),
  Cap:  int(nPrinters),
}
s := *(*[]PrinterInfo5)(unsafe.Pointer(&hdr))
for _, t := range s {
  fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: Have you done deserialization with a byte buffer in C? Unfortunately I think you're going to have to do something similar here. Meaning, you need to know the layout of the data represented by the bytes, instantiate your type, then assign to each field accordingly, moving through the buffer until all data has been read. There's a package to help but it doesn't offer much abstraction, just some methods to convert binary to integers https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/

Comment: github.com/alexbrainman/printer does something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pPrnInfo))
```

in both places in the code above is wrong; it gives you a pointer to the slice header, not to the actual backing array. You want this instead:

```
uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pPrnInfo[0]))
```

(Since the backing array is contiguous, a pointer to the first element of the backing array is the same as a pointer to the backing array itself.)